# Can GNU Grep output a selected group?

Tags: linux, grep

Is it possible to use GNU grep to get a matched group from an expression?

Example:

```
echo "foo 'bar'" | grep -oE "'([^']+)'"
```

Which would output "'bar'". But I would like to get just "bar", without having to send it through grep one more time (ie. get the matched group). Is that possible?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can use `sed` for this. On BSD `sed`:

```
echo "foo 'bar'" | sed -E "s/.*'([^']+)'.*/\\1/"
```

Or, without the `-E` option:

```
sed "s/.*'\([^']\+\)'.*/\1/"
```

This doesn't work for multiline input. For that you need:

```
sed -n "s/.*'\([^']\+\)'.*/\1/p"
```

Comment: Thanks, had forgotten about sed. But to clarify, sed doesn't take the argument -E..

Comment: Hm, it does on my machine (Mac OS X). Upon further examination, in the man page: "The -E, -a and -i options are non-standard FreeBSD extensions and may not be available on other operating systems."

Comment: Okay, it doesn't on mine (debian), what is -E supposed to do?

Comment: It's similar to `grep`'s -E: "Interpret regular expressions as extended (modern) regular expressions rather than basic regular expressions (BRE's).  The re_format(7) manual page fully describes both formats."

Comment: -r seems to to that for me.

Comment: And I don't have -r. Oh well!

Comment: @jtbandes: You don't need the extended features for this expression.. I just requires 3 escape characters for `( ) +` use `\( \) \+`: This is effectively the same: `sed "s/.*'\([^']\+\)'.*/\1/"`

Comment: This doesn't work for multiline input. For that you need: 

`sed -n "s/.*'\([^']\+\)'.*/\1/p"`

Answer (score 36):

While grep can't output a specific group, you can use lookahead and behind assertions to achieve what your after:

> `echo "foo 'bar'" | grep -Po "(?<=')[^']+(?=')"`

Comment: `grep -P` is not available on all platforms. But if it is, using lookahead/behind is a very nice way of solving the problem.

Comment: Is grep intelligent with the look-behind assertions?  How does it perform with long look-behinds?  Is it integrating the look-behinds into some sort of ["suffix tree"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) with the rest of the regex?

Comment: Literally an article I accidentally found related to this example: https://franklingu.github.io/programming/2016/11/19/grep-and-show-capture-group-only/

Answer (score 10):

You can use `\K` to reset and discard the left hand match text along with a lookahead which is not added to the match text:

```
$ echo "foo 'bar'" | grep -oP "'\K[^']+(?=')"
bar
```

GNU grep only.